# Reload embedded javascript in templates (Grails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

well I got a (jquery) javascript in .js loading inside a template in grails , the first time it loads in the template, and the script works perfectly, but once I hit the button to change the content in the template , the javascript doesn't reload, but once I embedded javascript directly in the template it loads fine, but once I put it back in a .js it doesn't load again. any suggestion?

it works this way:

```
<g:javascript>

   code code

</g:javascript>
```

but doesn't work again if I use this:

```
 <script src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'hoverInfo.js')}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Can you give me feedback on my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

*once I hit the button to change the content in the template*...

do you reload the full page or just a portion via remoteLink/ajax?

I guess in the second case, the browser notices that it already loaded the js-source and will not reload it - hence will not execute it a second time...

I guess you will have to use the onSuccess event to execute the script a second time...

Answer (score 0):

Double check the location of the javascript source file, which can be different when loading the page. Therefore go in to the network tab of your firebug and check, whether the browser tells you 404, when pressing your ajax-button.